# Is their a way to add the new NER tag found in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to be able to compare the NER tag found compared to a known location of the original tweet. I am using twitter data and adding it to a pandas dataframe columns ; id, tweet, location. I then use spacy and NER to find the location using the below code (ideally just finding the NER entities; GPE and LOC), I need it to go into a new column.
So it would read: ID, Tweet, Known location, NER location. The main issue I have had is getting the tweet index the same as the new NER tag, as they dont always match up for example is two NER tags are found in one tweet.
Any help would be much appreciated. After I am going to analyse so any suggestions on good methods to use would be great so I can research more on them! Thanks

````
ents = [(e.text, e.start_char, e.end_char, e.label_) for e in doc.ents]
ent = ['GPE', 'LOC']

for ent in doc.ents:
  print(ent.text+' -- '+ent.label_+'-- '+spacy.explain(ent.label_))
table = []
for ent in doc.ents:
  table.append( [ent.text,ent.label_,spacy.explain(ent.label_)])
  #ent.start, ent.end - can also use these to see position of text
df3 = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Entity', 'Label','Label_Description']) #to use above ones add in here - 'start','end',
#.sort_values(by=['Label']
print(df3)
DF1= df3.loc[df3['Label'].isin(['LOC','GPE'])]
gk2 = DF1.groupby('Entity').sum()
print(gk2) ```
````

Comment: Thanks for the comment, any suggestions on the question???

Comment: There's no guarantee that there will be exactly one entity per tweet, and what to do about that isn't a programming problem. What do you want to do if a tweet says "I love New York and Antarctica"? It depends on your goal.

Comment: Ideally I want it to recognise any ner tags found within a tweet, like you mentioned. A new column with New York and Antarctic, showing any and all ner tags. I was wondering if I could use the ID to match and tracj

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your data in a variable called `df` using the `apply` method should give you straightforward solution. Maybe this helps:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd

df = <YOUR DATAFRAME OBJECT THAT HAS COLS id, tweet, location>
nlp = spacy.load(<SPACY MODEL OF CHOICE>)
loc_labels = ['GPE', 'LOC']
ner_locations = []

def get_NER_location(row):
    tweet_id = row['id']
    tweet = row['tweet']
    doc = nlp(tweet)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_ in loc_labels:
            ner_locations.append([tweet_id, ent.text, ent.label_, spacy.explain(ent.label_)])


df.apply(lambda row: get_NER_location(row))
ner_df = pd.DataFrame(ner_locations, columns=['id', 'ent', 'label', 'label_desc'])
merged_df = pd.merge(df, ner_df, on='id', how='outer')
```

Apologies in advance if the code has any typos as I directly typed it in here.